# How to measure the complexity of the ratio of two integers

Tags: fractions, ratio

I'm no mathematician, and so I humbly ask this to those who are better versed in the art than I.
I'm hoping for an "objective" measure of a ratio's complexity, so I can compare two or more ratios in a meaningful way. For example, 1/1 is the simplest I can think of. 1/2 is the next simplest. 3/2 is perhaps of equivalent simplicity to 1/2. But, 4/3 is more complex as is 7/4 while 40/27 is much more complex.

But how much more? And which of these two is more complex: 35/17 or 40/21? And by how much?

Intuitively, I was thinking of multiplying the numerator by the denominator, and perhaps getting the log of that. But if I use that approach, then a ratio and its reciprocal would be the same. For example, with the ratios 5/6 and 6/5 it seems to me that 5/6 is more complex, but I can't quite explain why, maybe because it's closer to 1.

Any opinions? Has this been answered before?

Thanks.

EDIT-- apologies for the confusion in the comments (thanks for commenting); I didn't communicate clearly enough in my example.

So a clearer example. My intuitive ranking from simple to more complex (limited to numbers between 1/2 and 2, which is what I'm interested in):

1/1, 2/1, 1/2, 3/2, 2/3, 5/3, 4/3, 3/5, 3/4, 5/4, 4/5, 6/5, 7/4, 7/5, 8/5, 5/7, 4/7, 9/5,  5/6, 7/6, 8/7, 11/6....

...as I continue the series my intuition becomes less certain: this series (as intuited) may be 'wrong", but the first few terms are definitely "right".

Comment: Why is 7/4 less complex that 4/3? Intuitively it is the opposite.

Comment: If you [edit] the question to show us how you would rank all the fractions with denominator at most $16$ (say) then perhaps we can help. Try to give us your reasoning. Until you do, @Anixx 's comment is relevant.

Comment: As expressed in the previous comments, it is entirely unclear what you mean by the complexity of a fraction (or its simplicity).  Giving a few examples of pairs of fractions in which you call one more complex than the other does not suffice.  "Gut feelings" don't cut it.  Are you suggesting, perhaps that non-repeating decimal representations are less complex (e.g., 1/4 = 0.25, whereas $1/3 = 0.3\bar{3}$?  That might explain why you suggest that 5/6 = $0.83\bar{3}$ is more complex than 6/5 = 1.20.

Comment: @amWhy, decimal representation is not relevant to my problem. I think 6/5 is simpler than 5/6 because the denominator is smaller, and it's further away from 1 as a consequence, so I think absolute difference from 1 is a consideration

Comment: Why is $5/3$ simpler than $4/3$?  Roughly speaking, numerator + denominator$^2$ seems to be close to your order.

Comment: @Anixx no I meant that 4/3 is less complex than 7/4 (I should have put a comma in the correct place to grammatically clarify the meaning of my example)

Comment: @Tel  Your "definition" or "intuition" is incredibly subjective.  You're saying that 1000000/10 is more complex than 1000000/7?

Comment: @RossMillikan I'm thinking 5-3=2 is greater than 4-3=1, and so the difference of 2/3,  is simpler than the difference of 1/3. So my intuition is also to do with proximity to simpler ratios-- if a particular ratio is closer to a simpler ratio, than another ratio, then it is more "complex", so ratios that are simple are also further apart from each other on the number line... but I might contradict myself in the example I posted, hence my uncertainty about it.

Comment: @amWhy, no I didn't say that 1000000/10 is more complex than 1000000/7. My intuition tells me the opposite in that specific example.

Comment: Are you thinking about using continued fractions? All rational numbers can be written as a finite continued fraction, so the more terms there are in the continued fraction, the more "complex" it is.

Comment: Yes, @Tel, you have contradicted yourself a number of times.

Comment: @TobyMak thanks, I haven't heard of continued fractions, maybe I should look at that.

Comment: Why 3/5 is less complex than 3/4?

Comment: I think you're simply fishing, and none of us can read your contradictory thoughts to understand what, if anything, you are asking.  But it certainly is NOT anything definable in an objective manner.

Comment: @amWhy Just to be clear, I appreciate your efforts to help me clarify my thought processes, and there may be some contradictions inherent in what I am presenting, which is actually why I am asking; my intuitions may certainly be "wrong", but that is just a matter of refining them, as a consequence of this dialogue. Now, having said that, do you mind identifying the contradictions? I suspect he truth probably exists somewhere within the contradictions.

Comment: The problem is, @Tel, this site is not a discussion board designed to help you slowly refine your thoughts.  When you have a question that can be answered in a correct manner, then post the question.  But this site is not, as I just said, a discussion forum.

Comment: @Anixx I think because 3/5 is further away from 5/5 than 3/4 is from 4/4, related to my reply to RossMillikan

Comment: @TobyMak: You should definitely post that as a (rather short) answer. "Continued fractions" are exactly what I thought of too. I started posting it as an answer, but you should get my up-vote.

Comment: There are a number of complexity measures for fractions used in Number Theory, but maybe none that align with your intuitions, Tel. In diophantine approximation, one may simply use the denominator as a measure of complexity, but then $1/7$ and $65537/7$ have the same complexity. Also, the sum of numerator and denominator is sometimes useful.

Comment: I don't know whether length of continued fraction is such a good measure – it would make $13/8$ more complicated than, say, $496/165$. Also, it only gives a partial order, since there are many fractions with continued fractions of any given length.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: That's a good pair of examples. Perhaps Tel will come away from here with a new concept of complexity. For myself, I consider the "Fibonacci fractions" the most difficult to simplify, at least pound-for-pound, i.e. for a given size of denominator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length of a continued fraction makes a fraction more (subjectively) complex.

All rational numbers can be written as a finite continued fraction, as there is an [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Calculating_continued_fraction_representations) that computes continued fractions, but only stops if the number is rational.

There is evidence to suggest that certain cultures find rational numbers with simple continued fraction representations more tuning. In Western music, the preferred interval for the minor third is $6:5$, or $[1; 5]$ in continued fraction notation. However, this interval can also be tuned as $32:27$, or $[1; 5, 2, 2]$. The first interval clearly has a more compact representation, so to Western ears, it sounds "nicer". ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(music)))

When comparing two continued fractions of the same length, the fraction with a larger final term might be considered "uglier" as it is closer to a rational approximation with fewer terms.

On the contrary, as Gerry Myerson suggests, fractions with large denominators might have short continued fraction representations and vice versa. This suggests there needs to be a trade-off between the length of the continued fraction and the size of the denominator.

Comment: this is amazing! I didn't want to reveal my application for the problem, because I thought it might bias or limit any range of answers, but this is exactly my application-- I am doing an analysis of musical intervals (pitch ratios) in scales and need a method to rank harmonic complexity as "objectively" as possible (culturally neutral). I'll have a look at the algorithm and adapt/implement it. Thanks.

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please give some motivation to your question so that others can help you better. There's no problem specifying what you want to ask, as if other people have other ideas to yours, they can just write a comment.

Comment: point taken, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I calculated ratios as continued fractions, as suggested, then used this ad-hoc method to calculate the complexity:

```
log2((number of terms)^2*(sum of terms)*(product of terms)*(value of final term)*denominator)
```

which seems to provide a reliable score for ranking purposes, with 1/1 yielding zero, 2/1 yields 2 etc. Here's a sample output of some code I wrote:

```
interval ratio: 2 1 continued frac: 2 complexity: 2.  
interval ratio: 1 1 continued frac: 1 complexity: 0.  
interval ratio: 16 15 continued frac: 1 15 complexity: 13.813781  
interval ratio: 6 5 continued frac: 1 5 complexity: 9.228819  
interval ratio: 32 25 continued frac: 1 3 1 1 3 complexity: 15.627563  
interval ratio: 4 3 continued frac: 1 3 complexity: 7.169925
interval ratio: 64 45 continued frac: 1 2 2 1 2 2 complexity: 17.983706
interval ratio: 112 75 continued frac: 1 2 37 complexity: 20.930124
```